# JustifyContent: "center" in React grid

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

EDIT: It seems like replacing <View> with <div> and forgoing StyleSheet.create and simply doing:

```
const container = {
  display: "grid",
  ...
};
```

solves the issue. If anyone could explain why justifyItems doesn't work with <View> that would be helpful!

END OF EDIT======================================================

I have a grid with boxes and I want to centralise the contents. Many css styling guides just say to use justify-items: "center", however, it does not seem to work here.

Here is a rough example which I've been testing on.

```
function GridPage() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.item}></View>
            <View style={styles.item}></View>
            <View style={styles.item}></View>
            <View style={styles.item}></View>
            <View style={styles.item}></View>
            <View style={styles.item}></View>
        </View>
    );
}
  
export default GridPage;
  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display: "grid",
        height: 250,
        gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr 1fr",
        gridTemplateRows: "auto",
        justifyItems: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        borderColor: "green",
        borderWidth: 10,
    },
    item: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: "blue",
    },
});
```

If you do run this code, the blue boxes still lean to the left suggesting that the justifyItems: "center", is being ignored.

[image: Blue boxes aren't centralised]

However, the exact same code works when I convert it to html and css. What is happening and how would I resolve this?

Comment: Try with justifyContent: 'center'

Comment: there must be something else which is causing this - can you share a MVCE (stackblitz or codepen) which can recreate this issue?

Comment: @AkberIqbal I think you're right. I tried it on code pen and I couldn't get <View> to work so I replaced it with <div> instead. https://codepen.io/james-ji/pen/oNxvYWO It seems to work. I went back into my own code and replaced all <View> with <div> and it worked as intended. Kind of weird though.